# How can I have ntpd act as a client only, and not a server?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to configure a linux machine for NTP, but don't want that machine to reply at all to other machines which may make requests.  But it will be acting as an NTP client, which means it will need to be able to read replies from other servers.  Will the "ignore" parameter to restrict accomplish this, or will that also block replies from other servers?

Comment: What distribution and ntp implementation?

Comment: A [common enough](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-283062-start-0.html) question. Client-only is easily done and no need to switch to `chrony`.

Comment: @doneal24 I'm curious. does that work for large randomised pools such as ntp.org? I note that in the example the time servers need to be explicitly allowed, so it's worth knowing at what stage the domain name is resolved for the `restrict` statement.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani It's for an embedded system built with Yocto, using the ntpd reference implementation I believe.

Comment: @doneal24 Thank you, that looks like a great start.

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically want ntpd?  There is another NTP client that is designed as a client only named [chrony](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chrony).  This seems a better alternative than starting with a server and trying to configure it down to only a client.

Comment: This is for a piece of embedded software.  It will actually have the ability to act as an NTP client only, server only, or both, so ntpd does seem to be required.  I just need to figure out how best to configure it for each of those situations.